# Android Studio Button Clock crashes program

Tags: java, android, xml, button, crash

While following the tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html, and got help form: [My First App crashes when pressing a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482461/my-first-app-crashes-when-pressing-a-button), I still (after reading the answers to the question) can't figure out how to fix the problem.

**My Code: AndroidManifest.xml**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     package="com.example.buttonactivity1.app" >
>
>     <application
>         android:allowBackup="true"
>         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
>         <activity
>             android:name="com.example.buttonactivity1.app.MainActivity"
>             android:label="@string/app_name" >
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>             </intent-filter>
>         </activity>
>         <activity
>             android:name="com.example.buttonactivity1.DisplayMessageActivity"
>             android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
>             android:parentActivityName="com.example.buttonactivity1.MainActivity"
> ```
>
> >
>
> ```
> </manifest>
> ```

**MainActivity.java:**

> package com.example.buttonactivity1.app;
>
> import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; import
>   android.os.Bundle; import android.view.Menu; import
>   android.view.MenuItem; import android.view.View; import
>   android.content.Intent; import android.widget.EditText;
>
> public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
>       public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.buttonactivity1.MESSAGE";
>
> ```
> /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
> public void sendMessage(View view) {
>     // Do something in response to button
>     Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
>     EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
>     String message = editText.getText().toString();
>     intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
>     startActivity(intent);
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>
>     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
>     return true;
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>     // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
>     // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
>     // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
>     int id = item.getItemId();
>     if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
>         return true;
>     }
>     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
> }
> ```
>
> }

**DisplayMessageActivity.java:**

> package com.example.buttonactivity1.app;
>
> import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; 
>   import android.os.Bundle;
>   //import android.view.MenuItem; 
>   //importandroid.view.View;
>   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
>   //import android.view.LayoutInflater;
>   import android.view.*; 
>   import android.content.Intent;
>   import android.widget.TextView;
>
> /**  * Created by Neil on 4/21/14.  */ public class
>   DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
>       @Override
>       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
> ```
>     // Get the message from the intent
>     Intent intent = getIntent();
>     String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
>
>     // Create the text view
>     TextView textView = new TextView(this);
>     textView.setTextSize(40);
>     textView.setText(message);
>
>     // Set the text view as the activity layout
>     setContentView(textView);
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>     // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
>     // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
>     // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
>     int id = item.getItemId();
>     if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
>         return true;
>     }
>     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
> }
>
> /**
>  * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
>  */
> public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
>
>     public PlaceholderFragment() { }
>
>     @Override
>     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
>                 container, false);
>         return rootView;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> }

**ActivityMain.xml:**

> ```
> <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
>     android:layout_weight="1"
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
>
> <Button
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="@string/button_send"
>     android:onClick="sendMessage" />
> ```

**fragment_display_message:**

> tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity$PlaceholderFragment"

Error (logcat):

> 04-22 16:15:23.433  23203-23203/com.example.buttonactivity1.app
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
>   04-22 16:38:28.402  24414-24414/com.example.buttonactivity1.app
>   D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM 04-22 16:38:28.402 
>   24414-24414/com.example.buttonactivity1.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1:
>   thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578) 04-22
>   16:38:28.550  24414-24414/com.example.buttonactivity1.app
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2154)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2537)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9157)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2149)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2537)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9157)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {com.example.buttonactivity1.app/com.example.buttonactivity1.app.DisplayMessageActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
>               at com.example.buttonactivity1.app.MainActivity.sendMessage(MainActivity.java:21)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2149)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2537)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9157)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

In the other question, I saw the "fragment_main.xml" and "activity_display_message.xml" files. Do I need to have them? is that what's causing the problem?

Comment: Solved by restarting Android Studio-Case Closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have got a problem about your Manifest file.

You added com.example.buttonactivity1.DisplayMessageActivity
but code try to run different path

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.buttonactivity1.app/com.example.buttonactivity1.app.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Comment: I don't see the error: the path is:  "com.example.buttonactivity1.DisplayMessageActivity", the correct path

Comment: Only edit your activity name at manifest like this It might be work com.example.buttonactivity1.app.DisplayMessageActivity

Comment: Okay, that didn't solve the error, but now it displays the text on the screen.

Comment: What's the new stacktrace then?

Comment: loccat? if so: Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.buttonactivity1.app/com.example.buttonactivity1.app.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yeah logcat writes stacktrace when error occured. Could you send the latest version of your manifest file please?

Comment: Sure. How? in the comments?

Comment: I'll put in an answer.

Comment: Solved by restarting Android Studio-

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.buttonactivity1.app/com.example.buttonactivity1.app.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

You failed to add `DisplayMessageActivity` to your manifest in an `<activity>` element.

Comment: @Coder10101: `<activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" />` as a child of `<application>` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.